# m-ary tree relation between vertices and leaves

Tags: graphs, trees

A full $m$-ary tree with $n$ vertices and  $i$ internal vertices has $n = m \cdot i + 1$ vertices and
$l = (m − 1)i + 1$ leaves.

How can I prove it?

I know that **$m$-ary tree** is a rooted tree such that every internal vertex has no more
than $m$ children. The tree is called a **full $m$-ary tree** if every internal vertex has exactly
$m$ children. An $m$-ary tree with $m = 2$ is called a binary tree.

Comment: What would be the correct relation instead of  l=m-i+1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vertex is either an internal vertex or a leaf. Since the number of all vertices is $n$ while the number of internal nodes is $i$, the number of leaves, $l$ is $n-i$.

Every vertex is identified as a child of an internal node  except the root. Since there are $i$ internal node, each of them having $m$ children, the number of vertices, $n$ is $m\cdot i + 1$.

Since $i= n-l$, we also have $n = m\cdot (n-l) + 1$. Or
$$(m-1)n = m\cdot l - 1,$$
which is the relation between the number of vertices and the number of leaves in a full $m$-ary tree.

Comment: I guess root is not an internal node. So when I apply n-i isn't it include root with leaves?

Comment: As I understand, [an internal node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology) is "is any node of a (rooted) tree that has child nodes",  although root is indeed a very special internal node.